# Does JES start initiators?

Tags: mainframe, zos

I have been asked this question and I cannot come to an agreement as to whether or not this is true or false.

Would it be a true statement to say that JES does not start initiators and that the Work Load Manager does?

I felt an inactive initiator which receives a job from JES was JES starting an initiator, would this be correct?

I would appreciate any input on this as there as I am confused.

Comment: What is the purpose of the question? Why does it matter? Which JES (2 or 3 or both)? Since JES2 and JES3 existed before WLM, there's a definitive answer in the past, but why do you actually need to know? What is the real question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bill! The truth is we are studying for an exam which is coming up, the exam provides a small selection of test questions and this is one of them. We have talked to senior system programmers about the sample questions but no one can agree on whether JES starts initiators or the work load manager does. I guess this comes down to semantics? I felt reaching out to other experienced people on Stackoverflow may provide clearer insight into this. The reason we need to know is because after many discussions it is still unknown. The question does not state which JES. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. It is a Q&A site. There happens to be a web forum for Mainframe Beginners and Students, where this type of question is a better fit. http://www.ibmmainframeforum.com. Without a more specific question on what is being sought, I'd go with Kevin's answer. Knowledge for knowledge's sake is one thing, but a question with an actual purpose is more likely to have an actual answer, rather than possible debate on terminology, inflection and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bill I shall check out the IBM mainframe forum! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to meeting service class goals, WLM doesn't directly do anything itself; it works through other system components to do things, primarily Supervisor and JES.

WLM tells JES2/JES3 to start initiators if there's work waiting in a jobclass that has WLM managed initiators and the work is either part of the most important service class that isn't meeting its goals, or the system has idle capacity, and WLM doesn't think that starting another initiator will impact more important work.

As Bill said, though, the purpose of the question isn't really clear, and your terminology is confusing.  With WLM-managed initiators, there aren't inactive initiators, assuming there's work available for the jobclass.  WLM starts and stops actual address spaces as needed, based on the work available and the system capacity.